# Linq to SQL - How to verify a record doesn't exists before inserting

Tags: linq-to-sql

I'm working on a little side app for a client whereby they provide me with a list of cities and I have to insert them into the database and associate them with their parent records.

Example:

```
ID   |   PID   |   Region
1         0         California
2         1         Los Angeles
3         1         San Fransisco
```

Now my code looks like this

```
    Dim input As StreamReader
    Dim index As Integer
    Dim filename As String
    Dim RegionDC As New DAL.RegionsDataContext



    For Each TextFile As String In Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/app_data/business-trader cities/"))
        input = File.OpenText(TextFile)
        filename = New FileInfo(TextFile).Name
        index = 0


        ''# this is where we want to select the ID for the filename'
        Dim _ID = (From R In RegionDC.bt_Regions _
                 Where R.Region = filename.Replace(".txt", "") _
                 Select R.ID).FirstOrDefault

        While Not input.EndOfStream

            Dim q = (From r In RegionDC.bt_Regions _
                     Where r.Region = input.ReadLine() _
                     Select r.ID).FirstOrDefault

            ''# ***********************************'
            ''#  HERE IS WHERE IM TRYING TO VERIFY'
            ''#  IF THE RECORD EXISTS OR NOT'
            ''# ***********************************'

            ''# now we loop through the txt file'
            ''# and insert the data into the database'
            Dim oRegion As New DAL.bt_Region
            oRegion.Region = input.ReadLine()
            oRegion.FSSearchCount = 0
            oRegion.WSearchCount = 0
            oRegion.PID = _ID

            RegionDC.bt_Regions.InsertOnSubmit(oRegion)
            RegionDC.SubmitChanges()

        End While

        ''# clean up the locked files'
        input.Close()
        input.Dispose()
    Next
```

So basically if Los Angeles is in the TXT file, I don't want it re-entered into the database since it already exists.

Can anyone help me figure out how to verify if a record already exists prior to inserting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[LINQ To SQL Samples - EXISTS/IN/ANY/ALL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/bb737925.aspx#anysimp)

```
Public Sub LinqToSqlExists01()
    Dim q = From c In db.Customers _
            Where Not c.Orders.Any()

    ObjectDumper.Write(q)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that no record can have ID of 0, I think it's just a matter of testing whether `q = 0`.

But I think you have a bug in the code: you call `input.ReadLine()` twice in each iteration, so you test whether Los Angeles is already in the database and then try to insert San Francisco. Just capture the line in a variable and then use that.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (RegionDC.bt_Regions.Any(r => r.Region == input.ReadLine()))
{
    // Yes it exists
}
else
{
    // No it doesn't exist
}
```

Used a [converter](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/) to make the VB version :)

```
If RegionDC.bt_Regions.Any(Function(r) r.Region = input.ReadLine()) Then
    ''# Yes it exists 
Else
    ''# No it doesn't exist 
End If
```

Comment: @rockinthesixstring were you able to figure this out? If this answer helped you don't forget to mark it as the accepted answer.